# Cassandra read performance almost a constant with replication

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am stress testing cassandra with 8 nodes and eventhough I increased replication factor the read performance is almost a constant. I inserted 1000000 objects to the cluster and exactly 2 objects would be read many times so that those 2 objects become much popular. Others are accessed uniformly at random. Because I only read objects (no writes after the initial insert), I expected an increase of read performance when increase the replication factor. Instead, it remains almost a constant. Could you please help to figure out this behaviour?

Comment: You're probably limited by your client, rather than the server(s). But unless you post your code, nobody here can tell you that.

Comment: I am using Yahoo Cloud Service Benchmark (https://github.com/cmatser/YCSB/tree/cassandracql) framework in order to stress cassandra. Regarding the load, I am increasing clients so from resource utilization I can see the cluster is well stressed with 3 clients. I am running this in DigitalOcean $10/month instances (https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/). 
My setup is 8 instances make the cassandra cluster and 3 instances runs the YCSB clients each executes 500000 read requests.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the replication factor will not increase your read performance. Replication factor provides the concept of **`Data Availability`**. Which means, if the corresponding node get downs then the data is retrieved from the replication node. So the query time will be same what ever your replication factor is.

Refer **http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/architecture/architectureClientRequestsRead_c.html**

you can get idea of about how the cassandra read works. If you want to increase your read performance then your data modelling should be in good manner. Which means your column family schema and your query should give support of good read performance. Without your column family schema and your query it is hard to explain further(I agree with @kdgregory comment). For data modelling refer **http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/ddl/ddl_anatomy_table_c.html**.

Comment: IMHO replication factor can allow to load balance reads on replicas and improve read performance provided that consistency level is ONE

Comment: Your answer helps but now I got another issue, because I did the same tests in Amazon EC2 instances (Earlier tests were done in Digital ocean which gave almost constant results) and it gave higher throughput in lower replication factors but when increase, the read performace decreased in a significantly. For instance, read throughput with replication 1 = 9200requests/sec with replication factor 8 = 7200requests/sec. I am using YCSB framework for stress testing and I have a simple table with 10 fields only. Each row has 1KB of ASCII data.

Comment: Please note that I have disabled read_repair_chances for all my tests.

Comment: What is your query consistency level? If consistency level is more then there might have a chance to reduce read performance. If number of replicas is 8 and consistency level is 3 then it must query 3 replicas node simultaneously to maintain data consistency. Please add your column family schema and your query. Performance depends upon these parameters too.

Comment: My read consistency level is ONE. And write consistency level is ALL. (I made write consistency to ALL in order to make sure that when loading data it completes the replication as well). Please see the schema and query below comment

Comment: Schema: create table usertable (
     y_id varchar primary key,
     field0 varchar,
     field1 varchar,
     field2 varchar,
     field3 varchar,
     field4 varchar,
     field5 varchar,
     field6 varchar,
     field7 varchar,
     field8 varchar,
     field9 varchar) with speculative_retry='NONE' and read_repair_chance=0 and caching='ALL';

Query: Select * from usertable where y_id=<key> (key :this is selected according to the HotSpot distribution)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a token aware client as well.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this problem.
In order to do it, Cassandra setting we required to disable was dclocal_read_repair_chance.  Even though this settings was said to be disabled by default, it was not in my experiment. Also we reduced the object count to 10000.
Finally, we could see actually a performance increase for 80% read and 20% write access distribution at replication factor 2 and 3. Moreover, at replication factor 2 we saw a performance increase when 60% read and 40% write access distribution.